# How would I get a character to move up/down with keyboard? [Roblox/Lua]

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm new to Roblox scripting (although I've done plenty of Unity dev in the past) Basically I'm trying to allow the user to fly around. Turned gravity to 0, and wrote the ControlScript below. I want to make Space/Shift allow for people to go up/down. For some reason, this just doesn't modify the y-axis position though. I've been fiddling with this for like 4 hours now and I can't find what the issue is.

Thank you in advance for the help!

```
-- Declare variables
local userInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local runService = game:GetService("RunService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local moveVector = Vector3.new(0,0,0)
-- Handle inputBegan event (when player first presses a key)
userInputService.InputBegan:connect(function(inputObject)
 if player.Character then
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.W then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,0,-1)
   end
   if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.A then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(-1,0,0)
   end
   if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.S then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,0,1)
   end
   if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.D then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(1,0,0)
   end
   if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Space then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,-1,0)
   end
   if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,1,0)
   end
 end
end)
-- Handle inputEnded event (when player releases a key)
userInputService.InputEnded:connect(function(inputObject)
 if player.Character then
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.W then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,0,1)
   end
   if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.A then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(1,0,0)
   end
   if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.S then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,0,-1)
   end
   if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.D then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(-1,0,0)
   end
   if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Space then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,1,0)
   end
   if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
     moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,-1,0)
   end
 end
end)
-- On renderstepped update the character's motion based on what keys
-- are currently being pressed
runService.RenderStepped:connect(function()
 if player.Character then
   player:Move(moveVector, true)
 end
end)
```

Comment: This might be due to network authority. You might need to use events to communicate with the server then handle movement on the server.
EDIT: Player:Move might not work with Y axis so you might want to add velocity instead.

Comment: Thank you, this worked :) Posted the final script below

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard and mouse map is useful if you are not sure which button corresponds to a given action. To view this map:

1. Click on menu button located in the upper-left corner of the screen.
2. From this screen you can make a few mouse adjustments. As long as the developer hasn't set the camera mode for the game, you can toggle between two different modes and turn on/off Shift Lock. Additionally, you can set your avatar's movement mode. For more information on these settings,
3. To view the Roblox mouse and keyboard controls,

Answer (score 0):

Got this working using velocity, as per Evan Wrynn's suggestion. Here is the ControlScript:

```
-- Declare variables
local userInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local runService = game:GetService("RunService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local MyBody

local children = workspace:GetChildren()

for i=1,#children do
   if children[i].Name == player.Name then
   MyBody = children[i].HumanoidRootPart
   end
end

local moveVector = Vector3.new(0,0,0)
local velocity = 0

-- Handle inputBegan event (when player first presses a key)
userInputService.InputBegan:connect(function(inputObject)
  if player.Character then
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.W then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,0,-1)
    end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.A then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(-1,0,0)
    end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.S then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,0,1)
    end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.D then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(1,0,0)
    end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Space then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,-1,0)
      velocity = 10
    end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,1,0)
      velocity = -10
    end
  end
end)

-- Handle inputEnded event (when player releases a key)
userInputService.InputEnded:connect(function(inputObject)
  if player.Character then
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.W then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,0,1)
    end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.A then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(1,0,0)
    end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.S then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,0,-1)
    end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.D then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(-1,0,0)
    end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Space then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,1,0)
      velocity = 0
    end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
      moveVector = moveVector + Vector3.new(0,-1,0)
      velocity = 0
    end
  end
end)

-- On renderstepped update the character's motion based on what keys
-- are currently being pressed
runService.RenderStepped:connect(function()
  if player.Character then
    player:Move(moveVector, true)
    MyBody.Velocity = Vector3.new(MyBody.Velocity.X,velocity,MyBody.Velocity.Z)
  end
end)
```